# How can I listen on local link address 169.254.169.254

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, web, networking, webserver

I am looking to start a `HttpListener` on local link address and serve  requests from it. (similar to what AWS and Azure do for metadata services).

However, I get the following exception when I add the `http://169.254.169.254/` url prefix and start. `System.Net.HttpListenerException: 'The format of the specified network name is invalid'`

Is there some configuration step that needs to done ? How does Azure manage to do it.

Comment: Also, remember that you are not allowed to statically assign a link-local address in that range. The address must be randomly generated.

Comment: Do you mean I cannot assign that local link IP to my NIC if I want to ? What prevents it ?

Comment: The RFC explains the rules around the link-local address range, including that a host uses a pseudo-random number generator to assign the address, the link-local range cannot be subnetted, packets with link-local address cannot be routed, etc. Hosts should also do a duplicate address detection when assigning the address, but that is not mandatory.

Comment: It would also seem that listening on `0.0.0.0` would also get traffic through your link-local addressed interface.

Comment: Azure and AWS do this inside the Hypervisor software that runs the virtual machines.

Comment: I started TcpListener on `0.0.0.0` and then send a web request to `169.254.169.254`. It did not connect. May be its because link local address is not assigned to my NIC and looks like I cannot do a static assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Does 'netsh http show iplisten' show that the system is listening on the 169.254.169.254 address? On a typical Windows system, 169.254.x.y is a APIPA IP address that it assigns itself if it can't find a DHCP server.

Comment: I did try `netsh http add iplisten 169.254.169.254` but no luck. Same exception.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).